# how do i execute tcpdump on iphone?

Tags: ios, iphone, tcpdump

I could successfully run the following command on simulator

```
tcpdump -i en0 -A -vvv host www.facebook.com
```

I used the following code

```
 NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setLaunchPath: @"/usr/sbin/tcpdump"];
[task setArguments: [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"-c",@"10", @"-i",@"en1",@"-A",@"-vvv",@"host",@"www.facebook.com", nil]];

NSPipe *pipe= [NSPipe pipe];
[task setStandardOutput: pipe];

file = [pipe fileHandleForReading];

[task launch];
```

when i run this code on iPhone it gives following error

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'launch path not accessible'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x2f4a5f4b 0x398e66af 0x2f4a5e8d 0x2fe93081 0x12933 0x31c1d37b 0x31c1d139 0x31c23e05 0x31c214db 0x31c8c08d 0x31c88e59 0x31c83353 0x31c1e41f 0x31c1d721 0x31c82b3d 0x3410170d 0x341012f7 0x2f4709df 0x2f47097b 0x2f46f14f 0x2f3d9c27 0x2f3d9a0b 0x31c81dd9 0x31c7d049 0x12f2d 0x39deeab7)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

i have tried removing "/usr/sbin/" from code when running on iphone still it gives same error.Where am i going wrong?

Comment: are you installed tcpdump before ?

Comment: i have not installed on the device.is it compulsory that i should install.Can u please specify the tools name plz.

Comment: I think you should jailbrock your device and install `tcpdump` from `cydia`

Comment: so we cant do do this without jailbreaking our device.

Comment: we have a jail broken device how do use tcpdump command

Comment: try it in ssh terminal for sure that package installed and work

Comment: @sage444: We installed tcpdump from cydia and when we run the App in device, we got the error. Error is "tcpdump: (no devices found) /dev/bpf0: Permission denied". How can we fix this?

Comment: the problem is that app run without root privileges. I can't help with it, please google for "iOS run app as root"